# How to center a vertical aligned menu in css?

Tags: html, css

Here's the HTML code itself

```css
html {
  background: url(wallpaper.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: impact;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-right: 500px;
  color: gray;
}

#introduction {
  font-family: times;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #1F1B1B;
}

.paragraph {
  text-indent: 20px;
  color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

.rap {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: georgia;
  background: rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.4);
  width: 130px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 19px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#2pac">2pac</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Bigge Smalls">Biggie Smalls</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Nas">Nas </a></li>
  <li><a href="#Jay Z">Jay Z </a></li>
  <li><a href="#T.I.">T.I.</a></li>
</ul>
```

What can I do to center my menu itself? It keeps floating to the left and I want the whole thing dead center in my mock website.

Answer (score 0):

Change the links to be `inline-block` and assign `text-align: center;` to the parent to center the links, then remove the default `padding` from the ul so that everything is centered exactly in the middle.

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: georgia;
  background: rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.4);
  width: 130px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 19px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#2pac">2pac</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Bigge Smalls">Biggie Smalls</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Nas">Nas </a></li>
  <li><a href="#Jay Z">Jay Z </a></li>
  <li><a href="#T.I.">T.I.</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
  background: url(wallpaper.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: impact;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-right: 500px;
  color: gray;
}

#introduction {
  font-family: times;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #1F1B1B;
}

.paragraph {
  text-indent: 20px;
  color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

.rap {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
/**use text-align**/
ul li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  }
ul li a {
  display: inline-block; /*use inline-block display*/
  text-align: center;
  font-family: georgia;
  background: rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.4);
  width: 130px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 19px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#2pac">2pac</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Bigge Smalls">Biggie Smalls</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Nas">Nas </a></li>
  <li><a href="#Jay Z">Jay Z </a></li>
  <li><a href="#T.I.">T.I.</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally love another trick, quick and easy. Put it in a div container:

```
<div id = "menu">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#2pac">2pac</a></li>
     <li><a href="#Bigge Smalls">Biggie Smalls</a></li>
     <li><a href="#Nas">Nas </a></li>
     <li><a href="#Jay Z">Jay Z </a></li>
     <li><a href="#T.I.">T.I.</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Then, give the menu a fixed width and use auto margins, like this:

```
#menu {
width: 1000px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Or you can use the same styles on the ul itself.